# How to get the values in between below string using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this value in my mysql table called item.Item is a column name, I want to get the values present in between two date values using query. How to get that.
eg. i want from 2017-2-6 to 2017-02-07 values.
Please guide me. Its a string value

```
2017-02-06_CHAWAL,2017-02-07_RAJMA,2017-02-08_ROTI,2017-02-09_BENGAN MASALA,2017-02-10_DAAL
```

Comment: no its not like that its a string

Comment: I think you should start with a basic book or tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You need to have separate table column with date. So you need to split this `2017-02-06_CHAWAL` to

| date  |      name      |

| 2017-02-06 | chawal |

Then you, can use between:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-02-05' AND '2017-02-07'`

Comment: but i want the item associated with the date too like 2017-02-7_CHAWAL. my MAIN MOTO IS TO COUNT THE ASSOCIATED eg.  _CHAWAL OF THE DATE

Comment: Still you should split those values. Each table column should contain one type of data. In your case one field contains two of them date and a string. I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but this what you are trying to reach, is not usefull, you will not be able to use the power of mysql. If you will split those data you can use this kind of query:

`Select date, COUNT(name) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-02-05' AND '2017-02-07' GROUP BY name`

Comment: ok  Thanks Galileox86

Comment: Did this solved you problem?

Comment: no not yet Galileox86

Comment: but i cant afford to seperate it and store in table now....i want some runtime solution